# SWIG_exception() prints SWIG_RuntimeError as string

Tags: c++, exception, lua, swig

I wrapped my C++ function using SWIG so I can use it in Lua.

Inside my typemap, I check if the input is table.

```
if (!lua_istable(L, 1)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: table expected");
    }
```

But if this is called in Lua, the message prints like the following.

```
SWIG_RuntimeError:argument mismatch: table expected
```

I tried to replace `SWIG_RuntimeError` with `-3` but then it just prints `-3` instead of `SWIG_RuntimeError`.

I included the followings

```
%include <stl.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_except.i>

%include <exception.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
```

I tried not including `<std_except.i>` and/or `<exception.i>` but none of these fixed the problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the actual problem here?  You don't want it to print `SWIG_RuntimeError` or do you want to print something else?  Keep in mind that Lua has no support for exceptions, so SWIG converts C++ exceptions to Lua `error`.

Comment: The Lua generator of SWIG simply defines `#define SWIG_exception(a,b) { lua_pushfstring(L,"%s:%s",#a,b);SWIG_fail; }` and `#define SWIG_fail {goto fail;}`.  The block at `fail` simply calls `lua_error(L);`.

Comment: @HenriMenke When I generate errors in Lua, they normally print like `[string "; function bang() ; pd.setArray("arr" , "123"..."]:1: expected a table` which shows exactly where the error is happening. However my wrapped function simply prints `SWIG_RuntimeError:argument mismatch: table expected` which is not as informative as the first one so I thought maybe `SWIG_RuntimeError` should be converted to other string in Lua to specify where the error is happening. But maybe I was wrong about this. Is it possible to make it automatically print like my first example using `SWIG_exception()`?

Comment: If you want to know where the error is in the Lua code, just look in the stack traceback.  To find where the error is in the interface file, you have to adjust the exception generator, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dislike the standard exception handler of SWIG, you simply write your own one.  This will, however, not be portable across generators.

This is my interface file:

```
%module typemaps

%{
#include <vector>
void test_typemap(std::vector<int>) {}
%}

%define lua_exception(msg)
    lua_pushfstring(L, "%s:%d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, msg);
    SWIG_fail;
%enddef

%typemap(in) std::vector<int> {
    if (!lua_istable(L, 1)) {
        lua_exception("expected table for first argument");
    }
}

void test_typemap(std::vector<int>);
```

This is the Lua input file:

```lua
local typemaps = require("typemaps")
typemaps.test_typemap({1,2,3})
typemaps.test_typemap("not a table")
```

This is the error message:

```
lua5.3: test.i:15: expected table for first argument

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'typemaps.test_typemap'
    test.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

The first line tells us the point where it went wrong in the interface file.  In the stack traceback we then find where it went wrong in the Lua input file, namely at line three (`test.lua:3`) where we try to call `test_typemap` with a string.  The stack traceback is actually generic to Lua and has nothing to do with SWIG.  You'll always get one when you call `error`.

Comment: Thank you! I will give you bounty.